# Trigger the release of released memory?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

My app keeps crashing due to low memory issues when used "to fast" or lets say to "steady".

The app itself consists of many screens with a lot of layered graphics on them.
In order to not load to much data into the memory I release all loaded content the moment the user leaves one screen and then start loading the graphics for the next screen and display them.

That works well in most cases but there is a way to crash the app and i have no idea how to prevent it.

If the user keeps navigating from screen to screen, with no real pause, the memory is not being freed even so the objects are released or at least the release method is called. The memory is getting fuller and fuller until either the user stops swiping or the app crashes.

When I monitor the memory usage with instruments (and with a onscreen display that shows the free physical memory) I see that once the user stops, and the app stands idle, it takes like five to ten seconds and then a big chunk of physical memory is set free at once. Like up to 90MB on my iPad.

I am pretty confident that there are no remaining references to the objects left. If a reference would still exist they would not get unloaded after a few seconds. So i have no real idea on how to improve in this matter.

Is there any way to tell the device to actually free the "released" memory? Or is there something "extra" i need to do besides calling release for all objects and make sure there are no references left?

**Update**

I found a lead on what might be the cause in a posting on cocoabuilder.com. It was stated there that layers removed from views are not actually released right away but with a delay of 6 to 10 seconds. What exactly matches the delay I am seeing. And it makes sense too.

As the Layers hold a references (.contents) to the images there is an active reference, holding the image in memory, until the layer is finally released.

I tried to remove the reference by setting `.contents = nil` but that did not solve the problem. There is still something missing that I am not seeing.

Comment: I suspect you don't understand Cocoa memory management as well as you should. Have you read [Apple's memory management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)?

Comment: That is a valid assumption ;). But i did read that guide before i posted my question and i was although on the recent techtalk and heard the sessions about ARC, MMR and the performance sessions. What has me puzzeled is, that if what i am seeing with instruments is correct (and i assume it is) pretty much every app should work in the same way and therefore should have the same problem. So there should be a rather commonly known solution. But if there is, i can not find it...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using `-[NSAutoreleasePool drain]` which "Triggers garbage collection if memory allocated since last collection is greater than the current threshold."

**Update** It's also wise to use `release` and not `autorelease`. One gets triggered immediately, the other takes a few seconds, as you have observed.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I made some changes to use release instead of autorelease but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: You can't just use `-drain` willy-nilly. It has to be used in the context of an autorelease pool you've created in code, and once used, that pool is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

If you are releasing objects, but are not finding the memory being freed up, then you are over retaining your objects and not actually fully releasing them. What you are experiencing is a whole lot of memory leaking going on. Try running your app under Instruments and use the Leaks tool.

Comment: The memory is actually freed up, just not right away. So i made the assumption that it is not a over retaining problem or leak and i could not find leaks with insturments.